# VBA: How to loop through multiple variant arrays of the same length and turn them into Objects

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have 3 separate `variants` that are all arrays consisting of 13 rows and 1 column. One variant represents `names`, another represents `changes` and the last represents `occurrences`. Please see my starter code below:

```
Sub watchList()

    Dim names As Variant
    names = Sheets("Watch Calculations").Range("B4:B16")
    
    Dim changes As Variant
    changes = Sheets("Watch Calculations").Range("G4:G16")
    
    Dim occurances As Variant
    occurrences = Sheets("Watch Calculations").Range("G22:G34")
    
    
End Sub
```

I also have a class called `counterParty` with the following fields:

```
Public Name As String
Public changeStatus As String
Public negativeOccurences As Integer
```

How can I loop through all 3 variants at the same time and input the values into an object of the `counterParty` class based on the row number of each variant. Please see psuedo code below:

```
 Dim i As Integer
    Dim MyArray(1 To 13) As Integer
    For i = 1 To UBound(MyArray)
        
         'psuedo code stars here

         create new object of class counterParty
         set object.Name = names(i,1)
         set object.changeStatus = changes(i,1)
         set object.negativeOccurences= occurrences.get(i,1)

         add object to array of counterParty objects
    Next i
```

Comment: When you write `names.get(i)` you probably mean `names(i, 1)`?

Comment: @JohnSUN yes that is absolutely what I mean (sorry for the confusion, I'm used to java)

Comment: Shouldn't each of those variables (`names`, `changes`, `occurrences`) be of type [`Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range(object))?

Comment: @Paul No, it's storing the value of each cell in an array not setting a range.

Comment: @Warcupine - A Range is also a type of object; by defining the variable as the Range ([as per the link from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range(object))).  Using Variants introduces issues into your code as VBA tends to 'assume' in certain situations.

Comment: @Paul But the goal isn't to iterate through a range, the goal is to store the values of a range as an array and iterate through all arrays at the same time. Using a variant array of variants shouldn't cause any issues here, and is pretty standard practice as arrays are faster than ranges.

Comment: @Warcupine - Yes, I do realise that.  A Variant does *not* speed up the process for the first block of code `watchList()`.  If the OP was referring to a value in a single cell, then I could accept what you're saying, but they're not; they're referring to a *range* of cells.  Even with VBA defining sub-types for its `Variant` type, there's still a test and conversion process takes place, and this does not make the code easier to read.  If you have some evidence to the contrary, however, I'd love to see it.

Comment: @Paul it isn't faster to assign the variable but it is to access it / write it to a sheet. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

Comment: @Warcupine - Did you read the initial block of code?  There are no arrays there...

Comment: @Paul The OP's first block of code? Those are arrays, try the code.

Comment: @Warcupine - Ah - I see; my apologies; that's truly awful!  No wonder it doesn't make any sense.  I didn't read far enough down Pearson's page - rather than the logical assumption that the Variant would assume a type of `Range`, it doesn't, it picks up the values and morphs into an array... Just ugly!  Thankfully I don't have to work with this much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out

First the class module:

```
Private pName As String
Private pchangeStatus As String
Private pnegativeOccurrences As Long

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property

Public Property Let Name(lName As String)
    pName = lName
End Property

Public Property Get changeStatus() As String
    changeStatus = pchangeStatus
End Property

Public Property Let changeStatus(lchangeStatus As String)
    pchangeStatus = lchangeStatus
End Property

Public Property Get negativeOccurrences() As Long
    negativeOccurrences = pnegativeOccurrences
End Property

Public Property Let negativeOccurrences(lnegativeOccurrences As Long)
    pnegativeOccurrences = lnegativeOccurrences
End Property
```

Then the module:

```
    Dim names As Variant
    names = Sheets("Watch Calculations").Range("B4:B16")
    
    Dim changes As Variant
    changes = Sheets("Watch Calculations").Range("G4:G16")
    
    Dim occurrences As Variant
    occurrences = Sheets("Watch Calculations").Range("G22:G34")
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim clsarr(1 To 13) As Object 'You can use lbound and ubound on names() to get dynamic values
    Dim mycls As Class1
    For i = 1 To UBound(names)
        Set mycls = New Class1 'Overwrite current object
        'assign values to the class properties
        mycls.Name = names(i, 1)
        mycls.changeStatus = changes(i, 1)
        mycls.negativeOccurrences = occurrences(i, 1)
        
        Set clsarr(i) = mycls
    Next i
```